# Only Partial Utilization of all Bandwidth 7Mbps/50Mbps

Tags: networking, download, bandwidth

## IDM using only 7 Mbps out of 50 Mbps

***Free Download Manager*** is Only utilizing 7 Mbps out of my 50 Mbps Download *See Pic 1*

However the Pfsense Firewall is showing almost 60 Mbps Download usage *See Pic 2*

FreeNAS also shows *60ish* Mbps

I know that Free Download manager is the only major network usage, **No Netflix, Youtube, Hulu**...etc

So... Given that the LAN Bandwidth running at a minimum of 200 Mbps UP/DOWN, WAN Bandwidth is at 50 Mbps DOWN / 5 Mbps UP, Drive currently has Minimal usage (Besides Downloading File)....

Why am I getting only 7 Mbps in Free Download Manager (*Same speed for several IDMs too; Eagle get, Download ninja, Flash get, DownloadThemAll*)

---

### ↓ **STATS FOR NERDS BELOW** ↓

---

***Download Physical Route***

- 50Mbps Cable
- Pfsense (Full-Duplex, 1000Mbps)

  - DDWRT Access point A (Full-Duplex, 1000Mbps)

    - Wired PC (Full-Duplex, 1000Mbps)

      - DDWRT Access point A (Full-Duplex, 1000Mbps)

        - Cisco 2950 gb/01 (Full-Duplex, 1000Mbps)

          - Cisco 2950 **Link Aggregation(** * fa/05 (Full-Duplex, 100Mbps); fa/06 (Full-Duplex, 100Mbps)***)**

            - FreeNAS **Link Aggregation(** Full Duplex, 200Mbps **)**

***Network Info***

- Default gateway: 172.16.0.1
- DNS: 172.16.0.1, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4
- Network: 172.16.0.0/255.255.252.0

***FreeNas Info***

- IP: 172.16.3.246
- DNS: 172.16.0.1, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4
- Subnet: 255.255.252.0
- 9.10 Stable
- 4TB 7200 RPM SATA III 6 Gbps

  - CIFS SHARE(1 Client, ***Free Download Manager Host, Source***)
  - NFS SHARE (1 Client, Ubuntu Server, Destination)

Picture 1
[image]
Picture 2
[image]
Picture 3
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

7M**B**/s in actual file size is practically equivalent to 56M**b**ps bandwidth, so that's your 60Mbps you detect.

Download managers most of the time work with **B**ytes/s, while network equipment shows the information in **b**its/s.

This is clearly shown in you screen-shot.